# Drupal 7: How can I get path for node or term in drupal with php code?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I must build a block that retrieves children of a specific term id by selecting it through $node->title of a page.
So, I get it with taxonomy_get_termBy_name.
With this $term->tid I can get children of it by calling taxonomy_get_children().
Ok, it returns an array of children.
For each child I must take name and path in order to build an .
How can i retrieve these properties? 
I am unable to find a module that performs these operations, so I must build my own block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x) function to do this.

Example:

```
$link = l('Link Title', 'node/' . $node_id);
$link = l('Link Title', 'taxonomy/term/' . $term_id);
```